# What is the preferred file naming convention in Kotlin for a utility collection?

Tags: kotlin, naming

As being new to Kotlin, I'm not sure what the right name would be for a file like the following:

```
package de.company.carbase

import de.company.carbase.model.Car

typealias CarSupplier = () -> Car
```

I named it to `cars-utils.kt`. Only lower case and intentionally with a hyphen to distinguish it from regular class files.

This seems okay for me, but maybe there is an established convention I missed?

Comment: I've seen a library that uses lower-case file names for this kind of file, but it violates the official guide: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#source-file-names In this case I might suggest CarDeclarations.kt so it's obvious from the name that it isn't a class.

Comment: I've used `Extensions.kt` for miscellaneous extension functions that don't fit elsewhere, and `Utils.kt` for non-extension functions.  Though it's better to find somewhere relevant where possible.  However, in this case, is the typealias really needed?  The original type is shorter and clearer, and although that notation might look strange at first, it's widely used and you'll get used to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No doubt the correct answer should be: `CarDeclarations.kt`, as Tenfour04 remarked above.

Answer (score -1):

Kotlin naming convention for files is the same for class, objects, interfaces, enums, etc.

*HelperUtil.kt*

```
package org.example.project

fun simpleFunction(thing: Int): Int {}
```

This is now used by other files by importing like this:

*OtherFile.kt*

```
import org.example.project.simpleFunction

// simpleFunction can now be used in this file
```